# Python not able to distinguish between file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

Situation: Given the following Python3 code:

```
top = "/"
def traverse(top):
    filecount = 0
    dircount = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        path = os.path.abspath(root)
        print(path)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            dircount += 1
        elif os.path.isfile(path):
            filecount += 1
            #put the filepath into a function that hashes, then prints the hash
            md5hash(path)
```

Problem 1: Some directories do not get traversed, where the directory will be printed, but the subdirectories will not be printed.

Problem 2: Some directories were taken as files and therefore passed into the hashing function, which in return will throw an error that "it is not a file", effectively telling me that the Python function is confused between a file and a directory.

Additional Information: I am running on elementaryOS (Ubuntu 14.04), if it will help.

Comment: did you check permissions for the files and folders

Comment: Read permissions for "Others"? @ArpitSolanki

Comment: i ran this with sudo and its working fine on my system (ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I have a folder `/home/user/.config/enchant` which python is not going into.

Comment: And I am sure that there are multiple more

Comment: With this script with specified top = "/" it is not supposed to go in ` /home/user/.config/enchant ` I specified top as ` /home/arpit/.config ` and it was working fine. Also i specified top='/home/arpit' and it was able to go into folders like .npm and .nvm etc

Comment: Still not able to...

Comment: @ArpitSolanki never mind I finally understood what `root, dirs, files` stand for. Since I only printed `root`, the files inside will never be printed